# Bootstrap Progress Bar Not Showing Colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got this code from bootstrap, but it doesn't show the bar color. Do I need a CSS? How do I go about adding the color?

I got it from here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
        <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you including the bootstrap CSS in your page?

Comment: No, which bootstrap css?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` This isn't a fix, but add this to the top and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to import the Bootstrap CSS to use it:](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```